# Configurar Router para que pase por mi proxy creado en mi portatil con squid

Tags: redes, router, proxy

tengo un proxy en mi portatil con la herramienta: **squid** .

Desde el punto de vista de la red mi portatil, el proxy apunta a mi **localhost:1234** ,
quiere decir que para conectar mi router a dicho proxy seria :

**ipDeMiPortatil:1234**

Tengo un router de Vodafone, y no veo nada que hable exactamente de la palabra **proxy** , pero he encontrado las siguientes alternativas, pero no se si realmente es ahi donde deberia decir a mi router **que pase toda la informacion de mi red Local de casa por el proxy de mi portatil** . Comento los lugares del router donde creo que podria ser, por si alguien me puediera ayudar :

En la seccion **LAN** veo esto :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si el **DHCP Estatico** seria el lugar.

O si simplemente añadiendo a la **redireccion de puertos** seria suficiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Respuesta a **rgmagritte** :

En la seccion **DNS** que indicas tengo estos datos,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los proveedores que me da a elegir son :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me queda muy claro cual deberia de poner, ya que es dentro de la red donde deberia de buscar. Al igual que en los otros campos como cuenta y contraseña  y nombre de dominio. A demas, parece que como mucho podria poner solo uno, por tanto la opcion del **DNS de Google** no podria ponerla como salvaguarda, o eso creo.

Answer (score 0):

No se si mi respuesta aportará algo a tu cuestión, pero voy a intentarlo.

Salvo que te haya entendido mal, en mi caso, o por mi experiencia con un tema similar, tienes que decirle a tu router Vodafone, que las consultas de los clientes de tu red, debe enviarlas a la ip de tu portátil donde tienes configurado el proxy, por tanto para hacer esto, en el apartado DNS de tu router (es decir, donde veas las direcciones que usa tu router para realizar las consultas hacia fuera de tu red)  deberías especificar la ip de tu portátil, que finalmente será quien se encargue de recibir las peticiones de tu red y gestionarlas a través de las reglas que tengas especificadas en tu proxy.

Normalmente los routers de los ISP ya traen configuradas las direcciones DNS de sus propios sistemas, aunque tu las puedes cambiar y usar las que desees.

Como puedes colocar más de un servidor DNS yo pondría primero tu portátil, y como DNS secundario, cualquier otro que desees, como el de google (por ejemplo: 8.8.8.8) de esta forma, si tu portátil se apaga, podrás seguir navegando.

Respecto al puerto, no te haría falta especificarlo para este caso concreto, solo lo emplearías para el acceso a la consola de administración de squid poniéndolo junto con la ip de tu portátil en cualquier navegador.

Por cierto, por ahí en el menú de la izquierda, se ve un apartado que pone DNS&DDNS, creo que deberías empezar a mirar ahi (DNS). ;)

Espero que te pueda ser de utilidad mi respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder , de verdad. He mirado donde me has dicho y he actualizado la pregunta, porfavor revisala a ver si sabrias resolverme un par de dudas. 
De nuevo, mil gracias :)

Comment: Estas en el apartado correcto, pero olvídate de DDNS, eso es otra cuestión que ahora  no viene al caso.
Donde pone DNS te dice: "Alternativamente puede configurar sus propios DNs..." por ahí es por donde deberías mirar, tu router utilizara probablemente un par de servidores DNS (Probablemente de tu ISP) para poder realizar las consultas de tus equipos detrás del router a internet, lo que deberías hacer es decirle al router que en primer lugar le pregunte a tu proxy y después si no lo encuentra que utilice el DNS secundario si lo has configurado.

Comment: En que apartado de tu router esta no lo se exactamente, cada router de cada ISP puede variar, pero en general siempre se encuentra en un apartado donde puedes especificar tus propios DNS, si ahí no te aparece nada, puede que este bajo alguna opción de configuración avanzada, de lo contrario especifica el modelo de router por si alguien tiene el mismo y lo conoce para que te pueda ayudar específicamente. Otra opción es llamar a tu proveedor y pedirles ayuda con esta cuestión, para poder fijar tus propios servidores DNS. Tambien deberias tener en cuenta que servidores DNS utilizara tu squid....